# Installing rEFInd on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bootloader, efi

ALL,

I'm trying to follow an instruction [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#windows) to install rEFInd on top of my Windows 7 laptop.

Problem is - step 2 fail because apparently `mountvol` on Windows 7 does not have an option "/S". I tried to check on another laptop of mine - running Windows 8.1 with `mountvol --help` and it does show "/S" as an option available.

Does anybody know how to run this properly on Windows 7?

Thank you.

P.S.: Just wanted to add - Windows is completely up to date with the Office 2010 and MSVC 2010 installed.

Comment: rEFInf as the name suggests is for UEFI machines. Is yours a UEFI machine? Unlikely if it's just an old laptop with factory installed Windows 7.

Comment: Maybe the question you really want to ask is about the actual problem you're trying to solve with rEFInd?...

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, trying to follow the guide at https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/UEFI_Dual_boot_with_Windows_7/8#Optional:_Download_and_install_rEFInd_in_Windows to install Gentoo for dual boot. And I thought that all Windows machine are EFIs...

Comment: UEFI is a type of firmware that replaced BIOS a long time ago. If you're doing stuff like dual-boot or using Gentoo then you need to learn a lot more about hardware (BIOS/UEFI settings), partitioning and OSes requirements. One of those is knowing that Windows 7 can be installed in UEFI mode in UEFI machines (from USB, not from DVD) but typically wasn't when that Windows version was the factory installed default one, even in UEFI machines. In BIOS machines only BIOS mode can be used, obviously. The guide is **specifically for UEFI** and assumes Win7 installed in that mode (...)

Comment: The option "/S", by the way, *makes the ESP accessible as drive S:*. There's no ESP in BIOS. And this is just the tip of the iceberg of what you need to know.